# ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3 copyright issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently incorporating ffmpeg_kit_flutter into my project, and I'm curious about its copyright status. Can I freely use this plugin in my Flutter application for commercial purposes since it's licensed under LGPL-3.0? I'm not entirely clear on what that entails. Additionally, I'm facing an issue with the size of the package in my application. After integrating the plugin, the application size has become quite large. I've read suggestions about using the binary, but I'm unsure how to go about it. My intention is to utilize only the trim and crop functions. Any guidance on these matters would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked multiple questions here, let me go through them one by one.

1. Can you use `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` library for commercial purposes in your project - as per the LGPL v3.0 license, you can use it in your project without making any modifications to the existing library.
2. App size - there are multiple ways in which you can handle the app size, for example, using app bundles that splits APKs, moreover there's an open [issue](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/issues/638) and a guide available to decrease the size of the binary, you can follow this [wiki](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/How-to-Decrease-Binary-Size) which explains it quite well for the same.

Let me know incase you have any more doubts.

Comment: thanks for clearing me i also want to know  the difference between ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl: ^6.0.3  and ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3

Comment: The ffmpeg_kit_flutter package is a Flutter plugin that provides bindings for the FFmpeg library, allowing developers to use it in their Flutter projects for tasks such as audio and video processing, streaming, and more. The ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl package, on the other hand, is a specific variant of the ffmpeg_kit_flutter package that is built for different architectures and platforms, which may result in a larger APK size

Comment: So my main goal is trim the video , crop the video, convert MP4 to mp3 which one is best with compress size

Comment: You can go ahead with either of them for the features that you require in your app.

Comment: but how i can do it i don't have too much experienced reducing the size using ffmeg_kit package configuration

Comment: Then use this one ffmpeg_kit_flutter, this has comparatively smaller APK size. Here you wouldn't have to work on reducing the size yourself.